# What did i do wrong, i keep getting a message that row 12 is no good ( Sheets to calendar)

Tags: string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add events from sheets to calendar, i keep hitting an error with the last line of code

```
function addevents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("maytavbus.com_jm741jospf0kv3f2se2kpo88i0@group.calendar.google.com")
  var data = ss.getRange("A1:C" + lr).getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cal.createAllDayEvent(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2])
  }
}
```

I tried doing this, it is still telling me that the start has to be before the end, in sheets it is that way

```
function addevents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("maytavbus.com_jm741jospf0kv3f2se2kpo88i0@group.calendar.google.com");

  var data = ss.getRange("A1:C" + lr).getValues();

  for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var title = data[i][0];
    var startDate = new Date(data[i][1]); 
    var endDate = new Date(data[i][2]);
    cal.createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate);
  }
}
```

These is the data in the sheet:

```
title startDate endDate 
FAS8-school closed 11/1/2019 0:00:00 11/1/2019 0:00:00 
0647-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00 
SEM1-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00 
SME2-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00 
SMC3-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00 
SY2-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00 
SY5-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00
```

Comment: Please provide the actual error message.

Comment: Cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,string,string). (line 12, file "Code")Dismiss

Thank you @Cooper

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the spreadsheet you are working on? You have to provide a String and two Dates to the method [createAllDayEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-startdate,-enddate).

Comment: Column a has the event title, Column B is the start date and column C is the end date

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

`cal.createAllDayEvent(data[i][0], new Date(data[i][1]), new Date(data[i][2]));`

I'm assuming the last two are dates.

Comment: Event start date must be before event end date. (line 11, file "Code")       This is the code i got now

Comment: #dates vs Strings

Comment: Sounds like your event endDate is an earlier date than event startDate. Maybe you have them the other way around? Or maybe it's something else. Again, a sample of the spreadsheet might be useful.

Comment: title startDate endDate
FAS8-school closed 11/1/2019 0:00:00 11/1/2019 0:00:00
0647-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00
SEM1-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00
SME2-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00
SMC3-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00
SY2-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00
SY5-school closed 11/5/2019 0:00:00 11/5/2019 0:00:00
This is what should be porting

Comment: Are the start date and end date actual dates or are they strings and if there’s strings are they in a canonical form that the JavaScript date object constructor will recognize?

Comment: @Cooper please explain

Comment: When I'm reading data from a spreadsheet that contains date data I almost always do something like this var `dt=new Date(vA[i][0])` if it's a date then I just created an unnecessary date object but the script keeps running if it's a string that Date().constructor recognizes it will create the data and the script continues running with a Javascript Date() object.  This is why it's sometimes necessary to have access to an example spreadsheet.  If we had one by now we would have probably already solved your problem.  That's the reason for [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your comments on @Cooper answer, the startDate and the endDate are the same. That's the reason you are getting the error `Event start date must be before event end date. (line 11, file "Code")`.

If you want an event that lasts for only one day, you should provide only one date, as in [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-date). You should use [createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-startdate,-enddate) only if the event lasts for more than one day.

If some of the events only span one day and some many, you can add a condition that compare both dates, so that it uses a different method based on that condition.

So you can try changing this:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var title = data[i][0];
  var startDate = new Date(data[i][1]); 
  var endDate = new Date(data[i][2]);
  cal.createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate);
}
```

To this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var title = data[i][0];
  var startDate = new Date(data[i][1]);
  var endDate = new Date(data[i][2]);
  if(startDate.getFullYear() == endDate.getFullYear() && startDate.getMonth() == endDate.getMonth() && startDate.getDate() == endDate.getDate()) {
    cal.createAllDayEvent(title, startDate);
  } else {
    cal.createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate);
  }
}
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thank you @Omila! However some of these events span a few days

Comment: In such case, you can put a condition that compares startDate and endDate, and use a different method depending on that condition. I updated my answer with this.